# mysql timestamp displaying in seconds - how to display in java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rest

The timestamp '2015-06-15 13:01:48' which is stored in MySQL database is coming as 1434369708000 in my rest api response. How to handle so that the response also has the same format. I'm using Java, Hibernate, Restful WS with MySQL.

Entity:

```
private Date CreatedDateTime;

@Column(name = "created_Date_Time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
public Date getCreatedDateTime() {
    return createdDateTime;
}

public void setCreatedDateTime(Date createdDateTime) {
    this.createdDateTime= createdDateTime;
}
```

JSON View:

```
@JsonView({MessageView.class})
public Date getCreatedDateTime() {
    if (device != null) {
        return device.getCreatedDateTime();
    }
    return null;
}

public void setCreatedDateTime(Date CurrentServerUTC) {
    if (device != null) {
        this.device.getCreatedDateTime(CurrentServerUTC);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Jackson for serialization? If yes, which version?

Comment: Yes, using Jackson version 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html

On Entity try annotating CreatedDateTime with:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss")
private Date CreatedDateTime;
```

Double check the pattern though, I'm not %100 sure it's correct. It's the same as Java SimpleDatePattern string.

PS: non-static field names start with lowercase letter in Java as a convention.

I wrote a simple test to showcase this annotation:

```
public class JacksonDateTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

        om.writeValue(baos, new Sth());

        baos.write("\n Sth2 \n".getBytes());

        om.writeValue(baos, new Sth2());

        System.out.println(baos.toString());

        baos.close();
    }


    public class Sth {
        @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss")
        Date creationDate = new Date();

        public Date getCreationDate() {
            return creationDate;
        }

        public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
            this.creationDate = creationDate;
        }
    }

    public class Sth2 {
        Date creationDate = new Date();

        public Date getCreationDate() {
            return creationDate;
        }

        public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
            this.creationDate = creationDate;
        }
    }   
}
```

It works. Sth is serialized as:

```
 {"creationDate":"2015-06-16 16:09:06"}
```

while Sth2 is serialized as:

```
 {"creationDate":1434470946137}
```

There must be something else going wrong in your code.

Comment: this didn't work!  

PS: Oops! In the hurry to hide actual name I typed in caps.